# Google Spreadsheet Query IF(ISBLANK(), PARSE_ERROR:

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

With this Query I get this result. The idea is i have a date of the product that is sold. When check if the date is between date_start and date_end of the marketing table, if so put that price in the marketingprice.

In some cases there is no end. This mean it's still running and has no end date. We still use them.
Because there is no end date I want to use the date of today. So if E (date_end) is empty , use the today date if not then use E

```
=query(Marketing!$B$2:E,
"select C,D  where  B='" & D2 & "' and 
D<=date '"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and 
date'"&TEXT(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'>=date '"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ")

+------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
| product_no | product_price | amount | deliver_country |  datum   | marketingprice |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
|       1001 |           2.8 |      2 | de              | 2-1-2020 |                |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
+-----+------------+
| 3.2 | 01-01-2020 |
| 1.2 | 02-01-2020 |
+-----+------------+
```

I want to use IF(isblank(E),date'"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"', E)

Then the code will be

```
=query(Marketing!$B$2:E,
"select C,D  where  B='" & D2 & "' and 
D<=date '"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and 
IF(isblank(E),date'"&TEXT(today(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"',E)>=date '"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ")
```

Then I get a error:

> QUERY: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "IF "" at line 1, column 58.
>   Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Marketing Table

```
+---------+---------+-------+-------------+------------+
| channel | country | price | date_start  |  date_end  |
+---------+---------+-------+-------------+------------+
| Google  | de      |   3.2 | 01-01-2020  | 01-01-2020 |
| Google  | de      |   1.2 | 02-01-2020  |            |
| Amazon  | en      |   5.4 | 01-01-2020  |            |
+---------+---------+-------+-------------+------------+
```

Output how it should be

```
+------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
| product_no | product_price | amount | deliver_country |  datum   | marketingprice |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
|       1001 |           2.8 |      2 | de              | 2-1-2020 |            1.2 |
|       1002 |           3.8 |      4 | en              | 3-1-2020 |            5.4 |
|       1001 |           2.8 |      1 | de              | 1-1-2020 |            3.2 |
+------------+---------------+--------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
```

In mysql I use this code :

```
b.start_date                <= date(i.system_created)                                           AND   
coalesce(b.end_date,now())  >= date(i.system_created)
```

Solution i found myself:

```
=QUERY(Marketing!$B$2:$E;IF(Marketing!E$2:E="";
"select E where  B ='"&D2&"' and D <=date'"&TEXT(E2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and date'"&TEXT(VANDAAG();"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' >=date'"&TEXT(E2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' limit 1";
"select E where  B ='"&D2&"' and D <=date'"&TEXT(E2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and E >=date'"&TEXT(E2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"
);0)
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hoyRm0b7aSZrs7XNiulQQqnJwzC96kGiQXO9r3R_QfU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 ow sorry , can you try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(
 {Marketing!B$2:D\ IF(Marketing!E$2:E=""; TODAY(); Marketing!E$2:E)}; 
 "select Col2 
  where Col1 = '"&D2&"' 
    and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(E2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and Col4 <= "&TODAY()&"
  limit 1"; 0)))
```

Comment: you inserted it into query argument thats why it did not work. query supports only this: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

Comment: @ftft32 I tested player0 formula and it didn't give me `PARSE_ERROR`. Can you update your question, *Output how it should be* because the updated spreadsheet version doesn't match with data you posted in *Output how it should be*?

Comment: @JeffRush player0 did change it... you can find the old code in `Kopie van Sales`

Comment: @ftft32 would you mind if I give you solution with **Apps Script**?

Comment: @player0 this needed to be added   `order by Col4 desc`

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Apps Script** to solve this issue.

### How does it work?

1. Assign **Sales data** (*D2:E7*) to `sales` variable, **Marketing data** (*B2:E7*) to `marketing` variable.
2. in `for` loop through `sales` and if `sale_date < date_start` set cell value as `marketing_cost - 1`

Below you can find a screenshot attached before and after.

```js
function worker(){

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheetSales = ss.getSheetByName("Sales");
  let sheetMarketing = ss.getSheetByName("Marketing");

  // 1.
  let sales = sheetSales.getRange("D2:E7").getValues();
  /** sales
  [
    [de, 02-01-2020],
    [de, 03-01-2020],
    [de, 04-01-2020],
    [de, 06-01-2020],
    [de, 10-01-2020],
    [en, 10-01-2020]
  ]
  */
  let marketing = sheetMarketing.getRange("B2:E7").getValues();
  /** marketing
  [
    [de, 3.2, 01-01-2020, 02-01-2020],
    [de, 1.2, 03-01-2020, 04-01-2020],
    [de, 4.4, 05-01-2020, 06-01-2020],
    [de, 8.8, 07-01-2020, 08-01-2020],
    [de, 9.9, 09-01-2020, 25-02-2020],
    [en, 5.4, 01-01-2020, 25-02-2020]
  ]
  */

  let sale_date,
  date_start,
  date_end, 
  marketing_cost = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < sales.length; i++){

    sale_date = new Date(sales[i][1]);
    date_start = new Date(marketing[i][2]);
    date_end = new Date(marketing[i][3]);
    marketing_cost.push(marketing[i][1]);

    // 2.
    if(sale_date < date_start){
      sheetSales.getRange(2+i, 6).setValue(marketing_cost[i-1]);
    }else{
      sheetSales.getRange(2+i, 6).setValue(marketing_cost[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

### Before:

[image]

### After:

[image]

### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)